# Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, ros-noetic

I'm trying to create the costmap2dROS object using tf2 transform listener, but I always get the same error, I think it may be caused by the namespace, since I only have "robot_map" and "robot_baselink" instead of "map" and "baselink", but I don't know where to change to make it work.
Here's my launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
</launch>
<arg name="id_robot" default="robot"/>
<arg name="prefix" default="$(arg id_robot)_"/>
<arg name="x_init_pose" default="0"/>
<arg name="y_init_pose" default="0"/>
<arg name="z_init_pose" default="0"/>
<arg name="xacro_robot" default="summit_xl_std.urdf.xacro"/>
<arg name="launch_amcl_and_mapserver" default="false"/>
<arg name="launch_gmapping" default="false"/>
<arg name="launch_move_base" default="false"/>
<arg name="launch_robot_ekf_localization" default="false"/>
<arg name="robot_ekf_localization_mode" default="odom"/>
<arg name="map_file" default="empty/empty.yaml"/>    
<arg name="movebase_local_planner" default="teb"/>
<!-- odom, complete (including gps)-->
<arg name="omni_drive" default="false"/>
<arg name="ros_planar_move_plugin" default="false"/>
<arg name="launch_pad" default="false"/>
<arg name="use_gpu_for_simulation" default="false"/><!-- use_gpu_for_simulation -->
<arg name="has_pantilt_camera" default="false"/>
<!-- arm robot -->
<arg name="launch_arm" default="false"/>
<arg name="launch_moveit_movegroup" default="false"/>
<arg name="kinova_arm" default="j2s7s300"/>
<arg name="arm_prefix" default="$(arg prefix)$(arg kinova_arm)"/>

<!-- only for advanced simulation -->
<arg name="launch_advanced_simulation" default="false"/> <!-- one flag activates all -->
<arg name="launch_base_hw_sim" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_battery_estimator" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_perception" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_navigation" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_rlc" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_rlc_rostful" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="launch_hmi" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="rlc_rostful_host" default="localhost"/>
<arg name="rlc_rostful_port" default="8080"/>
<arg name="merge_lasers" default="$(arg launch_advanced_simulation)"/>
<arg name="merge_laser_topics" default="front_laser/scan rear_laser/scan"/>

<!-- GPS default position of Robotnik at Fuente del Jarro-->
<arg name="gps_latitude" default="39.5080331"/>
<arg name="gps_longitude" default="-0.4619816"/>


<!-- BEGIN ROBOT-->
<group ns="$(arg id_robot)">

    <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find summit_xl_description)/robots/$(arg xacro_robot)' 
            prefix:=$(arg prefix) 
            ros_planar_move_plugin:=$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin) 
            omni_wheels:=$(arg omni_drive) 
            gpu:=$(arg use_gpu_for_simulation) 
            gps_latitude:='$(arg gps_latitude)' 
            gps_longitude:='$(arg gps_longitude)' 
            --inorder"/>



    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <remap from="/joint_states" to="joint_states" />
    </node>

    <!-- Spawner model into gazebo -->
    <node name="urdf_spawner_summit_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
      args="-x $(arg x_init_pose)
            -y $(arg y_init_pose)
            -z $(arg z_init_pose)
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_1 0.0
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_2 2.9
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_3 0.0
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_4 1.3
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_5 -2.07
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_6 1.4
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_7 0.0
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_finger_1 1.0
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_finger_2 1.0
            -J $(arg arm_prefix)_joint_finger_3 1.0
            -urdf
            -param robot_description
            -model $(arg id_robot)" />


    <!-- start summit_xl_control nodes -->
    <include file="$(find summit_xl_control)/launch/summit_xl_control.launch">
        <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <arg name="sim" value="true"/>

        <arg if="$(arg omni_drive)" name="kinematics" value="omni"/>
        <arg unless="$(arg omni_drive)" name="kinematics" value="skid"/>

        <arg name="ros_planar_move_plugin" value="$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin)"/>
        <arg name="sim_arm_control" value="$(arg launch_arm)"/>
        <arg name="launch_pantilt_camera_controller" value="$(arg has_pantilt_camera)"/>

        <arg name="kinova_arm" value="$(arg kinova_arm)"/>
        <arg name="arm_prefix" value="$(arg arm_prefix)"/>
        <arg name="odom_broadcast_tf" unless="$(arg launch_robot_ekf_localization)" value="true"/>
        <arg name="odom_broadcast_tf" if="$(arg launch_robot_ekf_localization)" value="false"/>
        
    </include>

    <!-- robot_localization nodes, publishes transformation world->odom->base_footprint -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_robot_ekf_localization)" file="$(find summit_xl_localization)/launch/robot_localization_$(arg robot_ekf_localization_mode).launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- pad -->
    <include  if="$(arg launch_pad)" file="$(find summit_xl_pad)/launch/summit_xl_pad.launch"/>

    <!-- base_hw_sim -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_base_hw_sim)" file="$(find robotnik_base_hw_sim)/launch/summit_xl_hw_sim.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- imu_complementary_filter-->
    <node pkg="imu_complementary_filter" type="complementary_filter_node" name="complementary_filter_node" output="screen">            
        <remap from="imu/mag" to="mavros/imu/mag"/>
        <param name="fixed_frame" value="$(arg prefix)imu_link"/>
        <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
        <param name="publish_debug_topics" value="true"/>
        <param name="do_bias_estimation" value="false"/>
        <param name="do_adaptive_gain" value="true"/>
        <param name="use_mag" value="false"/>
        <param name="gain_acc" value="0.005"/>
        <param name="gain_mag" value="0.001"/>
    </node>


    <!-- amcl and map server base-->
    <include if="$(arg launch_amcl_and_mapserver)" file="$(find summit_xl_localization)/launch/map_server.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <arg name="map_file" value="$(arg map_file)"/>
        
    </include>
    <include if="$(arg launch_amcl_and_mapserver)" file="$(find summit_xl_localization)/launch/amcl.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <arg if="$(arg omni_drive)" name="odom_model_type" value="omni"/>
        <arg unless="$(arg omni_drive)" name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
        <arg name="x_init_pose" value="$(arg x_init_pose)"/>
        <arg name="y_init_pose" value="$(arg y_init_pose)"/>
        <arg name="z_init_pose" value="$(arg z_init_pose)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- move base -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_move_base)" file="$(find summit_xl_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <arg name="local_planner" value="$(arg movebase_local_planner)"/>
        <arg if="$(arg omni_drive)" name="differential_robot" value="false"/>
        <arg unless="$(arg omni_drive)" name="differential_robot" value="true"/>
    </include>

    <!-- gmapping -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_gmapping)" file="$(find summit_xl_localization)/launch/slam_gmapping.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- merge lasers -->
    <include if="$(arg merge_lasers)" file="$(find summit_xl_bringup)/launch/merge_laser.launch">
        <arg name="laserscan_topics" value="$(arg merge_laser_topics)"/>
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- MoveGroup Moveit! -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_moveit_movegroup)" file="$(find summit_xl_j2s7s300_moveit_config)/launch/summit_xl_j2s7s300_moveit_config.launch">
            <!--arg name="sim" value="true"/-->
    </include>

</group>

<include if="$(arg launch_perception)" file="$(find summit_xl_perception)/launch/perception_complete.launch">
    <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
    <arg name="run_reflector_locator" value="true"/>
    <arg name="run_ar_locator" value="true"/>
</include>

<include if="$(arg launch_navigation)" file="$(find summit_xl_navigation)/launch/navigation_complete.launch">
    <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
    <arg name="has_docker" value="true"/>
    <arg name="run_laser_docker" value="true"/>
</include>

<group if="$(arg launch_rlc)">
    <!-- start dock_manager node -->
    <include file="$(find summit_xl_robot_local_control)/launch/robot_local_control.launch">
        <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- start battery_estimation node -->
    <include if="$(arg launch_rlc_rostful)" file="$(find summit_xl_robot_local_control)/launch/rostful_server.launch">
        <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
        <arg name="host" value="$(arg rlc_rostful_host)"/>
        <arg name="port" value="$(arg rlc_rostful_port)"/>
    </include>

</group>

<include if="$(arg launch_hmi)" file="$(find robotnik_hmi)/launch/robotnik_hmi.launch">
    <arg name="id_robot" value="$(arg id_robot)"/>
    <arg name="launch_system_monitor" value="false"/>
</include>
```

and here's my code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "my_planner");

tf2_ros::Buffer buffer(ros::Duration(10));
tf2_ros::TransformListener tf(buffer);

costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS lcr("global_costmap", buffer);
costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap = lcr.getCostmap();

my_planner::PlannerWithCostmap pppp("planner", &lcr);

ros::spin();
return 0;}
```

It has been bothering me for days, I would appreciate it if any suggestion is provided.

Comment: A typical user of costmap data should not create a `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS` object. Instead, your ros node should subscribe to the costmap topic(s) published by `move_base`.